# Number table rows in Google Spread using Apps Script with file html in google drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'M newbie i am using google script to be able to import table from html file in my google drive. but now i have a problem that i don't know how to check that the data entered is the latest data. hope everyone can help.
My code using :

```
function myFunction2() {
var fileId = "1UqMZe3FlUWgqslL2lH6AjrwgDDYYzH9s";  
var spreadsheetId = "1ezNNoHNIalACU0gYiKSFrTkSXJNJewekRf0mP6yCWWc"; 
var sheetName = "Raw1";  
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
var sheetId = sheet.getSheetId();
var rowIndex = 0;
if (sheet.getLastRow() == 0) {

// Retrieve tables from HTML data.
var html = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getBlob().getDataAsString();
var values = html.match(/<table[\w\s\S]+?<\/table>/gi);
// Put the HTML tables to the Spreadsheet.
values.forEach(function (e) {
  var resource = { requests: [{ pasteData: { html: true, data: e, coordinate: { sheetId: sheetId, rowIndex: rowIndex } } }] };
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(resource, spreadsheetId);
  rowIndex = sheet.getLastRow();
  
 })

} else {
 sheet.clear();

}
```

}

Comment: Don't you need to parse <tr> and <td>?  And what are you comparing with to determine if "data entered is the latest data", date, equal values?

Comment: What do you mean 'is the latest data'? This script parses and pastes all the tables from the html file.

Comment: @TheWizEd:
first of all thank you for guiding me. I'm still a newbie so I don't know how to use the <tr> and <td> syntax.
and I am comparing the number of rows of data in the table in the html file and the number of rows on the sheet that has previously entered data to see the difference. If the number of rows on the html table is different from the line number of the previously entered data sheet, then I consider it a new data source and need to change. hope you help.

Comment: @Yuri Khristich:
first of all thank you for guiding me. The latest data in this case I get according to the data source of the table in the HTML file, as long as the data in the HTML file changes, the sheet will change accordingly. It can be understood that the number of data lines on the html file is different from the number of data lines on the sheet, so it is necessary to re-enter the data from the html table and on the html file there is only 1 table. hope you help.

Comment: Sorry, I still can't get the phrase: '_so it is necessary to re-enter the data from the html table and on the html file there is only 1 table._'. So you have the html file. Every time you run the script it fills the empty sheet with data from the table of the html file. If the html file was changed, you have to clear the sheet and run the script again. This way you're getting the 'latest data' from the html file. Do you mean __to add__ (at the bottom of sheet) the updated data from the html file whenever it changes?

Comment: @ Yuri Khristich : Sorry for not explaining clearly. What I mean is that when there is new data from the html file, delete all the current data on the Sheet and enter the data of the html file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clean the sheet before you run the script it can be done pretty easy:

```
function myFunction2() {
  var fileId = "1UqMZe3FlUWgqslL2lH6AjrwgDDYYzH9s";  
  var spreadsheetId = "1ezNNoHNIalACU0gYiKSFrTkSXJNJewekRf0mP6yCWWc"; 
  var sheetName = "Raw1";  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var sheetId = sheet.getSheetId();
  var rowIndex = 0;

  sheet.clear(); // clean the sheet <------------- HERE

  // Retrieve tables from HTML data
  var html = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getBlob().getDataAsString();
  var values = html.match(/<table[\w\s\S]+?<\/table>/gi);

  // Put the HTML tables to the Spreadsheet.
  values.forEach(e => {
    var resource = { requests: [{ pasteData: { html: true, data: e, coordinate: { sheetId: sheetId, rowIndex: rowIndex } } }] };
    Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(resource, spreadsheetId);
    rowIndex = sheet.getLastRow();  
  })
}
```

Or perhaps it makes sense to check if the html file has table before the cleaning:

```
function myFunction2() {
  var fileId = "1UqMZe3FlUWgqslL2lH6AjrwgDDYYzH9s";  
  var spreadsheetId = "1ezNNoHNIalACU0gYiKSFrTkSXJNJewekRf0mP6yCWWc"; 
  var sheetName = "Raw1";  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var sheetId = sheet.getSheetId();
  var rowIndex = 0;

  // Retrieve tables from HTML data
  var html = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getBlob().getDataAsString();
  var values = html.match(/<table[\w\s\S]+?<\/table>/gi);

  // Check if the html file has any tables
  if (values.length == 0) { 
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('The HTML file has no tables'); 
    return;
  }
  sheet.clear();

  // Put the HTML tables to the Spreadsheet.
  values.forEach(e => {
    var resource = { requests: [{ pasteData: { html: true, data: e, coordinate: { sheetId: sheetId, rowIndex: rowIndex } } }] };
    Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(resource, spreadsheetId);
    rowIndex = sheet.getLastRow();  
  })
}
```